# What 12 numbers in a C(12,2) and C(12,3) combination produce non-repeating sums?

Tags: combinations

this is my problem:

I need 12 distinct numbers, could be something like (3,9,15,17,27,etc.) that when added up either in combinations of 2 or 3, the sums do not repeat.

For example, if the numbers are 1-12, this is an issue because 2+3 and 1+4 both = 5

What 12 numbers would guarantee non-repeating sums?

Thanks!

Comment: $2^0,2^1,2^2,\dots,2^{11}$?

Comment: are you asking so that 2+2+1=1+4 is not allowed?

Comment: There is no *unique* set of such #s, e.g. $3^0, 3^1, 3^2$ .... e.g. would be another such set. $2^0, 2^1, 2^2,$.... is the simplest.

Comment: @trueblueanil I believe the powers of two do not work. Because adding three numbers is also allowed. Powers of three would work.

Comment: @wythagoras: I don't see why they shouldn't. Think of the numbers in binary form, *whatever* # of combinations you take, the # will be unique. With powers of 3, you can add and *subtract*, and still get unique positive integers, e.g, 1, 3-1, 3, 3+1, 9-3-1....

Comment: Both powers of 2 and 3 work!! Thank you guys so much!

Comment: By the way, I asked this question as a guest before I verified and created my account...i'm unsure how to choose the best answer...?

Comment: You can upvote  using up  arrows both answers and comments. And you can tick an answer to *accept* (i.e. it works for you).

Comment: @true, I don't think a 1-rep user can vote. Tick, yes; vote, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just to consolidate.

1, 2, 4, 8 ,16,..... i.e. $2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, ... 2^11$ is the **simplest** sequence that will serve your purpose.

You can see that easily by writing all possible combos in binary form, viz. 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, ...

and observe that each is unique.

You can have other sequences. 3^0, 3^1, 3^2, 3^3, .... will obviously do, but interestingly, besides adding combos, you can also **subtract** appropriately to get 1, 2, 3,.....$3^{n-1}$ , e.g.

1, 3-1, 3 , 3+1, 9-3-1, 9-3, 9-3+1, 9-1, 9, ......

This fact is used in the puzzle of a traveller who has a 40-link gold chain, and must pay the inn-keeper 1 link a day for 40 days.